# Check for column and bind grid if exists or not

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to bind data to `itemtemplate` of `gridview` at `RowDataBound` event. I am using a gridview and below is the code for that grid view.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCoreUtilization" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#cEcFcE"
                    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" OnRowCreated="grdPivot3_RowCreated"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="grdCoreUtilization_RowDataBound">
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblRoleID" Text='<%#Eval("RoleId") %>' runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                SupervisorName
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSupervisorName" Text='<%#Eval("SupervisorName") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                UserECode
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblUserECode" Text='<%#Eval("UserECode") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                UserName
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" Text='<%#Eval("UserName") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                Designation
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDesignation" Text='<%#Eval("Designation") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                L & D Training%
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblLDTraining" Text='<%#Eval("L & D Training%") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                Non Production%
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNonProduction" Text='<%#Eval("Non Production%") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                Process Support%
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblProcessSupport" Text='<%#Eval("Process Support%") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                Process Training%
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblProcessTraining" Text='<%#Eval("Process Training%") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                Production%
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblProduction" Text='<%#Eval("Production%") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                System Downtime%
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSystemDowntime" Text='<%#Eval("System Downtime%") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                Grand Total%
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblGrandTotal" Text='<%#Eval("Grand Total%") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Here i want to remove `EVAl` for binding the data to `itemtemplate`. In place of this i want to check weather

1. If all the Column exists in the `dataset`/`Datatable` or not which is mentioned in the Gridview.
2. If all Column exists  then bind that column to appropriate Itemtemplate .
3. If All column not exist then display and bind only available column and hide the not available column.

Query used:-

```
Select RoleId,SuperVisorName,Userecode,Username,Designation,TimeSpent,ActivityName 
                                from CoreUtilizationForRole1 where roleid=3
```

After executing the above query, i am doing a pivot on Activity column from c# and those columns are "L & D Training%","Non Production%","Process Support%","Process Training%","Production%","System Downtime%","Grand Total%" which i am binding on ItemTemplate.

Comment: Can you also add query here which you are currently use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblRoleNo = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblRoleId");
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblSupervisorName = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblSupervisorName");
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblUserECode = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblUserECode");
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblUserName = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblUserName");
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblDesignation = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblDesignation");
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblLDTraining = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblLDTraining");
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblNonProduction = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblNonProduction");
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblProcessSupport = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblProcessSupport");
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblProcessTraining = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblProcessTraining");
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblProduction = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblProduction");
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblSystemDowntime = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblSystemDowntime");
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblGrandTotal = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblGrandTotal");

            //Checking weather Columns exist in the Pivot or not

            var dataRow = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            var columnNameToCheck = "L & D Training%";
            var checkTraining = dataRow.Row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(x => x.ColumnName.Equals(columnNameToCheck, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (checkTraining)
            {
                // Property available
                lblLDTraining.Text = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "L & D Training%")).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblLDTraining.Visible = false;
            }


            var columnNonProduction = "Non Production%";
            var checkNonProduction = dataRow.Row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(x => x.ColumnName.Equals(columnNonProduction, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (checkNonProduction)
            {
                // Property available
                lblNonProduction.Text = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Non Production%")).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblNonProduction.Visible = false;
            }

            var columnProcessSupport = "Process Support%";
            var checkProcessSupport = dataRow.Row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(x => x.ColumnName.Equals(columnProcessSupport, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (checkProcessSupport)
            {
                // Property available
                lblProcessSupport.Text = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Process Support%")).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblProcessSupport.Visible = false;
            }

            var columnProcessTraining = "Process Training%";
            var checkProcesstraining = dataRow.Row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(x => x.ColumnName.Equals(columnProcessTraining, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (checkProcesstraining)
            {
                // Property available
                lblProcessTraining.Text = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Process Training%")).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblProcessTraining.Visible = false;
            }

            var columnProduction = "Production%";
            var checkProduction = dataRow.Row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(x => x.ColumnName.Equals(columnProduction, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (checkProduction)
            {
                // Property available
                lblProduction.Text = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Production%")).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblProduction.Visible = false;
            }


            var columnSystemDownTime = "System Downtime%";
            var checkSystemDownTime = dataRow.Row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(x => x.ColumnName.Equals(columnSystemDownTime, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (checkSystemDownTime)
            {
                // Property available
                lblSystemDowntime.Text = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "System Downtime%")).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblSystemDowntime.Visible = false;
            }

            var columnGrandTotal = "Grand Total%";
            var checkGrandTotal = dataRow.Row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(x => x.ColumnName.Equals(columnGrandTotal, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (checkGrandTotal)
            {
                // Property available
                lblGrandTotal.Text = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Grand Total%")).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblGrandTotal.Visible = false;
            }



            var columnNameToCheckRoleID = "RoleId";
            var checkRoleID = dataRow.Row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(x => x.ColumnName.Equals(columnNameToCheckRoleID, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (checkRoleID)
            {
                // Property available
                lblRoleNo.Text = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "RoleId")).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblRoleNo.Visible = false;
            }

            var columnNameToCheckSupervisorName = "SupervisorName";
            var checkSupervisorName = dataRow.Row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(x => x.ColumnName.Equals(columnNameToCheckSupervisorName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (checkSupervisorName)
            {
                // Property available
                lblSupervisorName.Text = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "SupervisorName")).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblSupervisorName.Visible = false;
            }


            var columnNameToCheckUserECode = "UserECode";
            var checkUserECode = dataRow.Row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(x => x.ColumnName.Equals(columnNameToCheckUserECode, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (checkUserECode)
            {
                // Property available
                lblUserECode.Text = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "UserECode")).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblUserECode.Visible = false;
            }

            var columnNameToCheckUserName = "UserName";
            var checkUserName = dataRow.Row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(x => x.ColumnName.Equals(columnNameToCheckUserName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (checkUserName)
            {
                // Property available
                lblUserName.Text = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "UserName")).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblUserName.Visible = false;
            }

            var columnNameToCheckDesignation = "Designation";
            var checkDesignation = dataRow.Row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(x => x.ColumnName.Equals(columnNameToCheckDesignation, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (checkDesignation)
            {
                // Property available
                lblDesignation.Text = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Designation")).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblDesignation.Visible = false;
            }


            //Changing color of the Pivot Data

            if (Convert.ToInt32(lblRoleNo.Text.ToString()) == 2)
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.GreenYellow;
            }
            if (Convert.ToInt32(lblRoleNo.Text.ToString()) == 3)
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Cyan;
            }
            if (Convert.ToInt32(lblRoleNo.Text.ToString()) == 4)
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
            }
            if (Convert.ToInt32(lblRoleNo.Text.ToString()) == 5)
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Pink;
            }






        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this on each of your template field. 
Set Visible property as following...
Visible='<%# !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("RoleId").ToString()) %>'

Answer (score -1):

this code provide you to hide particular cell from code behind if the value is blank...

```
Protected Sub gvCoreUtilization_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvCoreUtilization.RowDataBound
        Try
            If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

                Dim olblRoleID As New Label
                Dim olblSupervisorName As New Label
                Dim olblUserECode As New Label
                Dim olblUserName As New Label
                Dim olblDesignation As New Label
                Dim olblLDTraining As New Label
                Dim olblNonProduction As New Label
                Dim olblProcessSupport As New Label
                Dim olblProcessTraining As New Label
                Dim olblProduction As New Label
                Dim olblSystemDowntime As New Label
                Dim olblGrandTotal As New Label

                olblRoleID = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lblRoleID"), Label)
                olblSupervisorName = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lblSupervisorName"), Label)
                olblUserECode = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lblUserECode"), Label)
                olblUserName = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lblUserName"), Label)
                olblDesignation = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lblDesignation"), Label)
                olblLDTraining = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lblLDTraining"), Label)
                olblNonProduction = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lblNonProduction"), Label)
                olblProcessSupport = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lblProcessSupport"), Label)
                olblProcessTraining = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lblProcessTraining"), Label)
                olblProduction = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lblProduction"), Label)
                olblSystemDowntime = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lblSystemDowntime"), Label)
                olblGrandTotal = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lblGrandTotal"), Label)


                If CType(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "RoleId"), String) = "" Then
                    olblRoleID.Visible = False
                Else
                    olblRoleID.Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "RoleId")
                End If

                If CType(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "SupervisorName"), String) = "" Then
                    olblSupervisorName.Visible = False
                Else
                    olblSupervisorName.Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "SupervisorName")
                End If

                If CType(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "UserECode"), String) = "" Then
                    olblUserECode.Visible = False
                Else
                    olblUserECode.Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "UserECode")
                End If

                If CType(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "UserName"), String) = "" Then
                    olblUserName.Visible = False
                Else
                    olblUserName.Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "UserName")
                End If

                If CType(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Designation"), String) = "" Then
                    olblDesignation.Visible = False
                Else
                    olblDesignation.Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Designation")
                End If

                If CType(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "L & D Training"), String) = "" Then
                    olblLDTraining.Visible = False
                Else
                    olblLDTraining.Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "L & D Training")
                End If

                If CType(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Non Production"), String) = "" Then
                    olblNonProduction.Visible = False
                Else
                    olblNonProduction.Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Non Production")
                End If

                If CType(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Process Support"), String) = "" Then
                    olblProcessSupport.Visible = False
                Else
                    olblProcessSupport.Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Process Support")
                End If

                If CType(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Process Training"), String) = "" Then
                    olblProcessTraining.Visible = False
                Else
                    olblProcessTraining.Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Process Training")
                End If

                If CType(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Production"), String) = "" Then
                    olblProduction.Visible = False
                Else
                    olblProduction.Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Production")
                End If


                If CType(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "System Downtime"), String) = "" Then
                    olblSystemDowntime.Visible = False
                Else
                    olblSystemDowntime.Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "System Downtime")
                End If

                If CType(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Grand Total"), String) = "" Then
                    olblGrandTotal.Visible = False
                Else
                    olblGrandTotal.Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Grand Total")
                End If

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            General.LogException(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

And if you want to hide entire column in grid please follow below step

1) Create View state property on page for every column

```
 Property RoleId() As boolen
        Get
            If IsNothing(Me.ViewState("RoleId")) Then Me.ViewState("RoleId") = false
            Return CType(Me.ViewState("RoleId"), Boolean)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Me.ViewState("RoleId") = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

2) Loop throw Data-set for every column for each row and check value exist or not and set this property ,finally you have property with value true or false and you can find which column need to display in grid.

3)then you can easily hide column of grid.

```
if Me.RoleId= True then
'Write code to Display
else
'Write code to Hide
end if
```